# How to access Seconds_Behind_Master from SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to have access to the `Seconds_Behind_Master` field, (as returned by SHOW SLAVE STATUS) from inside a stored procedure.

I can't figure out how to get its value inside a variable.  None of the usual SET/SELECT syntax seems to work.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for the record: it has turned out to be possible to open a cursor for SHOW statements. This allows to parse the output and work with it inside a stored procedure.

Comment: Azerole, do you have sample code by any chance? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Yes, but it's 5.0 only. In 5.1 there is an unfixed bug in mysql that prevents opening cursors on SHOW.

Comment: @azerole Could you please publish the function, even if it is limited to 5.0?

Answer (score 2):

From what I see in the recent docs and [MySQL Bug#37187](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37187) there does not seem to be any way but `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` to get to this information.

Comment: The problem is that SHOW SLAVE STATUS can be used from the outside (e.g. from a perl script), but how can I parse it from a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2):

PHP can grab all the fields of the `show slave status` into a hashmap, like this:

```
$db = new pdo(
    "mysql:host=your_database_hostname;dbname=your_database_name",
    'your_username', 'your_password');

$sql = 'show slave status';

$query = $db->query($sql);
$res = $query->fetchall();

foreach($res as $item){
    print ">" . $item["Seconds_Behind_Master"];
}
```

Which prints 0 seconds because everything is up to date:

```
>0
```

I tried for an hour to create a stored procedure to do this.  I recommend you don't waste your time.